# Rails 5 - Load applications.css.scss as the last one in head

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

In my rails5 application, I have application.css.scss and controller specific stylesheets such as home.scss, about.scss etc.

When I check the inspect in my browser, it seems application.css is loaded before home.css and about.css. Because of this, most of the overrides used in applications.css were simply ignored.

**application.css.scss**

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require material-design-iconic-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min
 *= require nprogress-turbolinks5
 *= require app
 */
```

How can I load applications.css.scss as the last one in head section?